# AuthorizeCheckOperationFilter in Swagger 5 in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, swagger, swagger-ui

I've been using this method in an older version of Swagger:

```
        public class AuthorizeCheckOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
    {
        public void Apply(Operation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
        {
            var authAttributes = context.MethodInfo.DeclaringType.GetCustomAttributes(true)
                .Union(context.MethodInfo.GetCustomAttributes(true))
                .OfType<AuthorizeAttribute>();
            if (authAttributes.Any())
            {
                operation.Responses.Add("401", new Response { Description = "Unauthorized" });                    

                operation.Security = new List<IDictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>>
                                     {
                                         new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>
                                         {
                                             { "oauth2", new[] { "myscope" } }
                                         }
                                     };
            }


        }
    }
```

However, now the interface has changed into this:

```
    public class AuthorizeCheckOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

How do I convert the code? :-)

Many thanks!
Gunnar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could refer to the [official github doc](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/master/README.md#add-security-definitions-and-requirements) to change like below:

```
public class AuthorizeCheckOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        var authAttributes = context.MethodInfo
        .GetCustomAttributes(true)
        .OfType<AuthorizeAttribute>()
        .Select(attr => attr.Policy)
        .Distinct();
        if (authAttributes.Any())
        {
            operation.Responses.Add("401", new OpenApiResponse { Description = "Unauthorized" });
            var oAuthScheme = new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Reference = new OpenApiReference { Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme, Id = "oauth2" }
            };

            operation.Security = new List<OpenApiSecurityRequirement>
            {
                new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
                {
                    [ oAuthScheme ] = authAttributes.ToList()
                }
            };               
        }
    }
}
```